# Why my controller params always get single value from multi-select fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have defined a multiple select fields in my form:

index.html.haml

```
=form_for :mydata, {:url=>"/datas/render_datas", :method=>:post} do |form|

  =select_tag('cars',options_from_collection_for_select(@cars, 'id', 'name'), {:multiple=>'multiple', :class=>'cars'})

  = ...
  =form.submit "Get"
```

when I submit my form, application calls the controller's `render_datas` method:

```
class DatasController < ApplicationController
  def render_datas

    selected = params[:cars]

    # I always get the last clicked car item

    puts selected.to_s 

  end
end
```

From the rails console, I see the params holds the cars hash, but it always hold the last mouse clicked item, not the multiple selected array, why??? How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `multiple` option should be `:multiple => true`.